# ERROR: DLISModelOptCpu-0.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, python-wheel

I'm trying to install a wheel with the name `DLISModelOptCpu-0.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` onto my Windows machine. I'm currently running Python version 3.8.12, but from my (very limited) understanding of wheel names, my wheel needs version 3.6.x? Is there a way to get this to work without downgrading my Python version?

Edit:

```
$pip debug --verbose
Compatible tags: 30
  cp38-cp38-win_amd64
  cp38-abi3-win_amd64
  cp38-none-win_amd64
  cp37-abi3-win_amd64
  cp36-abi3-win_amd64
  cp35-abi3-win_amd64
  cp34-abi3-win_amd64
  cp33-abi3-win_amd64
  cp32-abi3-win_amd64
  py38-none-win_amd64
  py3-none-win_amd64
  py37-none-win_amd64
  py36-none-win_amd64
  py35-none-win_amd64
  py34-none-win_amd64
  py33-none-win_amd64
  py32-none-win_amd64
  py31-none-win_amd64
  py30-none-win_amd64
  cp38-none-any
  py38-none-any
  py3-none-any
  py37-none-any
  py36-none-any
  py35-none-any
  py34-none-any
  py33-none-any
  py32-none-any
  py31-none-any
  py30-none-any
```

I see `cp36-abi3-win_amd64` in my list of compatible tags. How can I get `cp36-cp36m-win_amd64` instead? And what's the difference between the two anyways?

Comment: Impossible. Python versions are not compatible related to binary extensions. Either get a newer wheel or install an older Python.

Comment: I edited my post a bit. It seems `cp36-abi3-win_amd64` is among my list of compatible tags, but `cp36-cp36m-win_amd64` is not. Could you explain to me the difference between `abi3` and `cp36m`?

Comment: I could but don't want to. It is currently an unimportant detail. What is important: you cannot screw an extension compiled for one Python version to work with a different Python version. They are not ABI-compatible. You can try to do hacks like manually extracting the wheel but sooner or later your Python fails with a fatal error. My advice is: don't go that route.